# Progress bar not moving

Tags: android, multithreading, progress-bar

I have progress bar in every item inside my listview. When I tap an item on the list, another thread makes the progress bar move. For some reason the output says the progress bar is increasing but it's not. Below is some of the code.

```
 mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) adapter.getView(pro, null, null).getTag();
                            Log.d("Progress",String.valueOf(vh.progress.getProgress()));
                            vh.progress.setProgress((int) prog[pro]);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: So this does post the progress: `Log.d("Progress",String.valueOf(vh.progress.getProgress()));`? Can you post the code where your "progress" visuals are?

Comment: sorry, i dont get what you mean

Comment: what is vh.progress? post that code

Comment: its all class that holds the progress bars in the listviews.  static class ViewHolder {public ProgressBar progress;

Comment: the "pro" variable is the index of the taped view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getView()` on your `Adapter` is probably creating a brand new row, since that's what it is supposed to do when you call `getView()` with a `null` second parameter.

You need to have a better scheme for retrieving the `ProgressBar` that you wish to update, taking into account that the `ProgressBar` may have been recycled to be displaying some other row's progress.

Comment: The only way I can think of retrieving the progress bars is to not recycle the views. There's only going to be an average of 10 views in the list and I'll prevent the list from eating up memory. Do you think I should do this?

Comment: So long as you keep it to "an average of 10 views in the list". The danger is that you'll forget that limitation and try scaling your approach up to 1,000 rows.